# Objective-C output syntax

Tags: objective-c, syntax

I am new to programming, does anyone have reference about this stuff?

```
%1f %2f
```

I know the f is means float number. Why put '1' before the f?

Comment: Is that the *exact* format you have seen?  I ask as using 1 and 2 for float types is not normal...

Comment: We can see from the OP's other question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11666737/objective-c-code-error/11666780#11666780) that this format specifier is used in a `sscanf()` statement; that is an important detail!

Comment: Using 1 and 2 still doesn't make sense even when used with `scanf()`.  Remove the 1 and 2 and try your code without it and you will be able to perform calculations on arbitrary floating point numbers, not just single-digit ones.

Comment: why the output is 0.00? 
2012-07-26 18:11:18.697 program6.8[1870:403] Type in your expression
12+1
2012-07-26 18:11:24.250 program6.8[1870:403] 0.00

Comment: You need to type in '12 + 1' (i.e. put spaces between the elements).

Comment: Well then put a breakpoint after the `sscanf`, debug the app, and see what values are being read into your variables.  Time to get self-sufficient.

Comment: if I change the double to float and '%f %c %f', the output is 24.00

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Field width

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/printf/

Comment: (Link is for C++, but for this one it applies to C and Obj-C as well.)

Comment: could you please give me some clear example for that? Thanks.

Comment: Examples are found on the bottom of the page. For some more examples, check this url: http://www.codingunit.com/printf-format-specifiers-format-conversions-and-formatted-output

Comment: does this "%3.2f" is same as "0.2f" ?

Comment: Don't know this from the top of my head, it's been a long while since I've seen C. You can write a quick function printing both %3.2f and %0.2f to see the difference, or closely read the manual.

Answer (score 0):

Google is you friend: See the [Apple developer documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html). Also check out the general [printf](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/printf.html) specification.