# objective-c code error

Tags: objective-c, xcode

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Calculator.h"
#import "ctype.h"
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    double value1,value2;
    char operator;
    Calculator *myCal =[[Calculator alloc]init ];

    NSLog(@"Type in your expression");
    scanf("%1f %c %1f",&value1,&operator,&value2);

    [myCal setAccumulator:value1];
    if (operator =='+')
        [myCal add:value2];

    else if (operator == '-')
         [myCal subtract:value2];

     else if (operator == '*')
         [myCal multiply:value2];

     else if (operator == '/')
             [myCal divide:value2];

     NSLog(@"%.2f",[myCal accumulator]);

    }
    return 0;
}
```

I cant find out any error about this code, I type code from the book, the code is same as on book. but the xcode tell me they have two errors, first one is 'Expected identifier or '('
second one is  'Expected external declaration'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a spurious brace before the `return` statement:

```
}  <--- remove this
return 0;
```

**EDIT**: Use this `sscanf()` statement instead so you can enter proper floating point numbers:

```
scanf("%f %c %f", &value1, &operator, &value2);
```